# Why does my template not reactive?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

If I first open http://localhost:3000/, then click the test link, the `roles` labels will be displayed.

But if I directly open http://localhost:3000/test(Input the url in Chrome's address bar and hit enter),  the `roles` labels will not be displayed.

Here is my code:

In client startup I subscribe to something:

```
 Meteor.publish("Roles", function(){
   return Roles.find();
 });

 Meteor.startup(function() {
   if(Meteor.isClient) {
     Meteor.subscribe('Roles');
   }
 });
```

And roles template:

```
 Template.roles.helper( {
   allRoles: function() {
     return Roles.find();
   }
 })
```

html

```
      <template name="roles">
      <div>
        {{#each allRoles}}
          <label>test label</label>
       {{/each}}
      </div>
    </template>
```

The problem is sometime `roles` template is rendered before the `Roles` is ready.
So these is no role labels displayed.

But according to Meteor document, helpers is a reactive computation, and Database queries on Collections is  reactive data source. So after `Roles` is ready, the `{{#with allRoles}}` is reactive and should be displayed.

Why does roles not be displayed?

And then I rewrite my code to:

```
 Meteor.startup(function() {
       if(Meteor.isClient) {
        roles_sub = Meteor.subscribe('Roles');
       }
     });

Template.roles.helper( {
       allRoles: function() {
         console.log(2);
         return Roles.find();
       },
       isReady: function() {
         console.log(1);
         console.log(roles_sub.ready());
         return roles_sub.ready();
       }
     })
```

html

```
<template name="roles">
  <div>
    {{#if isReady}}
    {{#each allRoles}}
      <label>test label</label>
    {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And still role labels cannot be displayed.
And console gives me:

```
1
false
1
false
1
true
2
```

Which means `isReady()` is reactive? but why my roles labels remains blank?

Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[Template.subscriptionsReady](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#blaze-3)**

server/publish.js

```
 Meteor.publish("Roles", function(){
   return Roles.find();
 });
```

client/client.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('Roles');
});

 Template.roles.helpers({ // --> .helper change to .helpers
   allRoles: function() {
     return Roles.find();
   }
 })
```

client/templates.html

```
<template name="roles">
  <div>
    {{# if Template.subscriptionsReady }}
      {{#with allRoles}}
        <label>{{> role }}</label>
      {{/with}}
    {{ else }}
      loading....
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="role">
  <div>{{ _id }}</div>
</template>
```

A reactive function that returns true when all of the subscriptions

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/9fe2f4b442ec84eac5352b476d014c977c5ae4a2/packages/blaze/template.js#L424

Comment: Not work if I directly open http://localhost:3000/test(Input the url in Chrome's address bar and hit enter),  the `roles` labels will not be displayed.

Comment: ah ok helper({})  --> helpers({}) ??